# about ES date range and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search by date range and phrase in title.
My elasticsearch version is 7.8.1
what's wrong with my code?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "range": {
              "create_time": {
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "from": "2000-01-01",
                "to": "3000-01-01",
                "include_lower": true,
                "include_upper": true
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "my name is here",
              "type": "phrase",
              "fields": [
                "title"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "create_time": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

I got error message:

```
"type": "parsing_exception",
"reason": "[and] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[and query is replaced by bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-and-query.html). You can combine `range` and `multi-match` query using [`bool/filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [          // note this
        {
          "range": {
            "create_time": {
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
              "from": "2000-01-01",
              "to": "3000-01-01",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "my name is here",
            "type": "phrase",
            "fields": [
              "title"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "create_time": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```